# ¿Como relacionar clases en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, .net

buenas tardes y buenas noches según la hora a la que leas esto.

Actualmente estoy construyendo una aplicación utilizando tecnologías de Microsoft como lo so .NET y SQL Server.

Tras modelar la base de datos y relacionar las entidades entre sí me di cuenta de que no tengo ni idea de cual es la forma correcta de realizar esas relaciones a nivel de código.

Tomando como ejemplo las siguientes tablas:

Tabla_Estados

- ID_Estado
- Estado

Tabla_Puestos

- ID_Puesto
- Puesto

Tabla_Empleados

- ID_Empleado
- ID_Puesto
- ID_Estado
- Nombre

Según las tablas de ejemplo, anteriormente mostradas, en mi código debería crear tres clases que correspondan a esas tres tablas anteriores ya que cada una debería contar con su set de métodos CRUD por lo que se tendría que manejar cada objeto de manera individual, sin embargo, habrán situaciones en donde necesite emular un JOIN para empaquetar toda esa información en la clase empleados.

Actualmente el único método que se me ocurrió fue agregar una referencia de la siguiente manera:

```
    public class Clase_Empleados
    {
          ID_Empleado int;
          ID_Puesto int;
          ID_Estado int;
          Nombre string;
             
          public virtual Clase_Puesto Puesto { get; set;}
          public virtual Clase_Estado Estado { get; set; }
    }
```

El método anteriormente mostrado me ha servido, sin embargo, me gustaría saber si es la forma correcta de relacionar clases o si de hecho estoy incurriendo en una mala práctica.

PD: Entiendo que Entity Framework sería la mejor solución, sin embargo, por petición del cliente, no es posible utilizar esa tecnología.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De lo que hiciste se ve bien pero aún te falta la relación en las otras clases. Quedaría algo así.

```
public class Estado
{
      [key]
      public int ID_Estado { get; set; }
      public string Estado {get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Empleado> Empleado { get; set; }
}

public class Puesto
{
      [key]
      public int ID_Puesto { get; set; }
      public string Puesto { get; set;}
      public virtual ICollection<Empleado> Empleado { get; set; }
}

public class Empleado
{
      [key]
      public int ID_Empleado { get; set; }
      public int ID_Estado { get; set; }
      public int ID_Puesto { get; set; }
      public string Nombre { get; set; }

      public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
      public virtual Puesto Puesto { get; set; }
 }
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Excelente amigo, no lo sabía.
Muchísimas gracias.
Saludos.